# grep command to find 'words' that begin and end with * (e.g., *way*, *then*)

Tags: grep

My original thinking was that this would work

```
grep -w '\*.*\*' /path/file-name
```

This produces some good hits but it doesn't respect the word option. I get whole lines. For example, like this

```
[bold]*way* to the store to buy some groceries and *then*[bold]
```

and I want to get this

```
[bold]*way*[bold] to the store to buy some groceries and [bold]*then*[bold]
```

Another one I get is this, which I thought wouldn't appear because it has spaces (which should disqualify it because I want only words or stuff separated by spaces)

```
* * *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the match *non-greedy*: in a basic (BRE) or extended (ERE) regular expression you can enforce that by using an exclusive character set `[^*]` in place of the inclusive `.*` i.e.

```
grep '\*[^*]*\*'
```

or

```
grep '[*][^*]*[*]'
```

If you a prefer perl-compatible regex, that has an explicit non-greedy modifier `?`

```
grep -P '\*.*?\*'
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work: '\*[^*]*\*'. Any idea why, for my own learning? The Pearl one works well though.